# A linear optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

We have the following equation:

$\sum_{i=1}^ny_i=A$

By considering this equation I want to find the minimum possible $B$ in the following equation to find the tightest bound and also when that $B$ is achieved.

$\min\Big(\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\sum_{j=1(j\neq i)}^my_{ij})\Big)\leq B,$

where, $m<n$ and we know that $\sum_{j=1(j\neq i)}^ny_{ij}=y_i.$

Comment: Please define the decision variables first, state the objective, and state the constraints. I strongly believe this will help you in future work.

Comment: If we know that $\sum_{j=1(j\neq i)}^my_{ij}=y_i$ isn't B always equal to 0?

Comment: I fixed the problem.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/37236/5038, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2079033/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.